# How are text messages added to html messages

Tags: mailgun

I'm using cURL to send Mailgun messages. One of the cURL arguments is `-F template='mytemplate' \`, which uses a template set-up on Mailgun.  How do I add a text version of the message?

Answer (score 0):

According to the MailGun API docs, you can request a text-only version by including the parameter `-F t:text='yes'` as part of your cURL request.

This will change the MIME Content-Type from `text/html` to `multipart/alternative` which most mail clients will render first as HTML, falling back to text if there's a problem. It's worth noting however, that this leaves the text interpretation up to MailGun meaning that you don't get any say in how the text is composed.

I've tested this a few times and ran into minimal issues, but if you want to ensure that your text comes through as intended, you're better off composing your own `multipart/alternative` MIME message and passing that to MailGun using the `/messages.mime` API endpoint.